# Get all hrefs with jquery or javascript and add it to header

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How do I grab all hrefs from a list with jquery or javascript and add it to header as "text/css"?

List:

```
    <ul class="active">
      <li><a href="/path/to/link1">link1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/path/to/link2">link2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/path/to/link3">link3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Desired result:

```
    <head>
    [...]
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/link1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/link2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/link3.css">
    </head>
```

I think there is a way to do this with something like this:

```
    <script>
    var hrefs = []; 
    jQuery('.active')
    .find('a[href]')  
    .each(function() {
        hrefs.push(this.href);
    })
    ;
    var code = '<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"' + hrefs + '\.css" />';
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = code;
    var head = document.head;
    while (temp.firstChild) {        
    head.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
            }
    </script>
```

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 3):

**jQuery:**

```
$('.active a[href]').each(function() {
  var $style = $('<link/>').attr({"rel":"stylesheet","type":"text/css","href":this.href});
  $('head').append($style)
});
```

For each anchor create a new `<link>` and pass the appropriate attibutues to it. Then append them to the head.

https://jsfiddle.net/dufn7vyt/1/

**javascript:**

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.active a[href]');
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
for (i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i) {
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.type = 'text/css';
  link.href = anchors[i].href;
  head.appendChild(link);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dufn7vyt/3/

Support for querySelectorAll

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: And is there a way to handle this with pure javascript?

Comment: Yes. Added pure javascript option as well.